# Registering Msi Server - Hangs on some machines

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, basic-msi

I have a basic MSI project created with InstallShield 2013
When installing the setup in silent mode on Win 7 64 bit I see that on several machines the installation takes a lot of time.
I already uninstalled  KB2918614, KB3000988 and KB3008627 and I don’t have SECREPAIR and SECUREREPAIR errors in MSI log.
I see that in most cases it hangs while Registering Msi Server... which appears many time in the log file
In most cases this action take less than a second but in others 15 minutes

Regular

```
InstallShield 9:36:53: Registering Msi Server...
InstallShield 9:36:53: Invoking script function CreateLogFile
```

Hang

```
InstallShield 9:36:54: Registering Msi Server...
InstallShield 9:53:15: Invoking script function CreateABCD
```

Are the InstallScript CA which I’m running cause the Registering Msi Server action to hang or there is no connection to the CA ?
What בשמ affects the time it takes ?

Answer (score 1):

Setup hangs, with wait cursor, no installation screen appear and nothing in task bar. 3-4 exe files of the same setup in Task Manager. I tried to create new setup by installing Microsoft Visual studio Installer projects extension. SAME result.

Then I found on web, Disable your antivirus programs for installation. It worked out. This installation problem was with 64 bit OS 8 /8.1/10.. i didn't check 7 64 bit

I needed to disable antivirus for application startup as well. There could be some settings in antivirus for allowing app, i don't know. but it worked out for me